# Colorbox dynamic resize on form submit

Tags: dynamic, resize, colorbox

I have a form that fits neatly into my colorbox. When the following validation function fires it creats dynamic labels that cause the form's height to pop a scroll bar.

I am trying to call $.colorbox.resize() every time the validation function runs but so far its not working?

My code so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logForm").validate();
    $("#logForm").colorbox.resize();
  });
</script>
```

form code

```
<div id="colorboxwrapper">
    <form action="login.php" method="post" name="logForm" id="logForm">
    <input name="doLogin" type="submit" id="doLogin3" class="button" value="Login">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
$("#logForm").colorbox.resize();
```

Should be this:

```
$.colorbox.resize();
```

Comment: Yea tried that, didnt fire off when the validation script ran. Validation works fine but the colorbox didnt resize to take into account the new height presented with the new error div the validation script poped in.

Comment: You need to call resize after validation has happened.  Read the documentation for your validator plugin and find out how you should do that.